# Obtener el primer día del mes anterior en SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta para obtener diferentes registros en el periodo de un año. Mi objetivo es realizarlo desde el día 1 del mes anterior al actual (como estoy en enero de 2023, quiero obtener datos de diciembre de 2022) hasta el día 1 de  13 meses hacia detrás (en este caso diciembre de 2021), lo que comprendería un rango de un año (como muestro debajo). Gracias!

```
select count(1), 'SOL_FECHA_ESTADO' as tabla from WESP_RPT.INFORME_CONTRAT
where (FECHA_VENTA_BRUTA >= to_date('01/12/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') 
and FECHA_VENTA_BRUTA < to_date('01/12/2022','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo siguiente extrae la fecha actual, la fecha hace un año, la fecha hace un mes, el primer día del mes de la fecha actual, la fecha del primer día del mes actual hace un año

```
DECLARE @TODAY AS DATETIME 
DECLARE @ONEYEARAGO AS DATETIME 
DECLARE @ONEMONTHAGO AS DATETIME
DECLARE @FIRSTDAYCURDATE AS DATETIME
DECLARE @FIRSTDAYONEYEARAGO AS DATETIME

SET @TODAY = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
SET @ONEYEARAGO = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @TODAY)
SET @ONEMONTHAGO = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @TODAY)

SET @FIRSTDAYCURDATE = DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(DAY, @TODAY) - 1), @TODAY)
SET @FIRSTDAYONEYEARAGO = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @FIRSTDAYCURDATE)


SELECT @TODAY AS FECHA_ACTUA, @ONEYEARAGO AS HACE_UN_ANIO, @ONEMONTHAGO HACE_UN_MES, @FIRSTDAYCURDATE AS PRIMER_DIA_FECHA_ACTUAL, @FIRSTDAYONEYEARAGO AS PRIMER_DIA_HACE_UN_ANIO
```

Adicionalmente en lugar de usar dos condiciones mayor y menor que sugiero usar la cláusula BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE FECHA BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIAL AND @FECHA_FINAL
```

**REFERENCIAS:**

DATEADD
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

DATEPART
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16